# Why isn't this CASE operator working?

Tags: mysql

```
    SELECT id, 
           created,
           CASE
             WHEN signed = 0 THEN 'no'
             ELSE 'yes'
    FROM resumes
```

Not sure why this is throwing the following SQL error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE

Comment: Can you provide the schema for the `resumes` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `END` at the end of your case statement:

```
SELECT id, 
       created,
       CASE
         WHEN signed = 0 THEN 'no'
         ELSE 'yes'
       END
FROM resumes
```

Comment: Most DBMSs also want an alias for the resulting column name. Does MySQL?

Comment: @KenWhite [Nope](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/66568), but it does make for one ugly column header.